# VBA to automate Internet Explorer 8 Error

Tags: javascript, excel, internet-explorer-8, vba

I am trying to automate a workflow process where we go into our internal internet website.

Click a button called import. A javascript window pops up. We select a value from a combobox. We need to select "Replace" value from different drop down menu below the combobox. Lastly, click the import button on the new window.

I am relatively new to VBA, and I was able to open the website and click the import button, but I can't reference the combobox in the javascript window. Also, I have Internet Explorer 8 and can't upgrade to 10 or 11.

I can't download a third-party software to automate this for me like autoit because this is my work laptop, and its restricted.

I've tried to use doc.getElementsById, but the code isn't finding the object.

Here is the code I have:

Sub modAutoLogin()

```
'Need to activate two references: Microsoft Internet Object and Microsoft HTML
'http://open-twebst.codecentrix.com/ use to record web macros

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim LoginForm As HTMLFormElement
Dim ImportButton As HTMLInputButtonElement
Dim cbo As HTMLSelectElement

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate cURL

'Wait for initial page to load

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Set doc = IE.document

'Get the only form on the page

Set LoginForm = doc.forms("aspnetForm")

Set ImportButton = LoginForm.elements(16) 'If I try to use LoginForm.elements("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnImport") it won't find the button

ImportButton.Click

Set cbo = LoginForm.GetElementById("FormularyComboBox_Input") 'If I try to use LoginForm.elements("FormularyComboBox") it cbo = nothing 

cbo.Value = "2015 GG"

End Sub
```

Here is what the HTML code looks like when I inspect the combobox in the javascript dialog box:

[image]

Comment: After the button click you may need another Do While loop waiting for IE to load the next form.

Comment: The HTML code you provided is not a real `<select> <option>` combobox. But there might exist a real combobox somewhere else in the DOM that containes the list and the value that you want to select. If you find it, then you can easily set the right "select" the value there.